# Log4j How do I stop my logger from printing the data to the console?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

```
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, fileAppender

# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\BIMPaaSAutomationFramework\\log\\Log_${log4j.now}_logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c{1}] - %m %n

log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
log4j.logger.httpclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=ERROR


log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.FileAppender=INFO
```

Below is my log4j.properties file, I need to stop printing the data to my console as, it is printing on console and file both , however i need it to print in my file only and not on console